# How to convert a file with class str type into python dictionary

Tags: python, json, unmarshalling

I wrote the below code:

```
import json
with open('json_data.json') as json_file:
    df = json.load(json_file)
```

that opens json file which look likes:

> {'api_version': None,
> 'kind': None,
> 'metadata': {'annotations': ....
> .....
> 'allocatable': {'cpu': '4',
> 'ephemeral-storage': '1055762868Ki',
> 'hugepages-1Gi': '0',
> 'hugepages-2Mi': '0',
> 'memory': '3953464Ki',
> 'pods': '110'},
> .......
> 'phase': None,
> 'volumes_attached': None,
> 'volumes_in_use': None}}

The type of this file is `<class 'str'>`. I want to convert this big string class into a more structure fomart like python dictionary in order to access allocatable variables like cpu , memory, etc.
What is the best approach or library that do it?
Note that, using *Unmarshal* function from *pymarshaler.marshal* library was not helpful.

Comment: What's wrong with `json.load`?

Comment: `json.load` does return an object. Did you look at [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) ?

Comment: How can a file be of class str?

Comment: I do not know where is the issue. this file is automatically saved by kubernetes.

Answer (score 0):

You have an issue with your json your feeding into the program. Take a look at this code which is using different json.

```
import json

### file.json text
### {"name":"John", "age":30, "car":null}

with open('file.json') as json_file:
    df = json.load(json_file)
    print(df)
    print(type(df))
```

This code produces dictionary for your df.

Comment: Thanks. This file is save automatically by kubernetes. I only can change the perfix of file to conver to text for instance. Then my code also has json.load and the type is class str.